# Can a request parameter take multiple values in an url?

Tags: request

Suppose I am doing a get request to the following:

```
https://test.com/api?state=1
```

Let's assume that state can take a value from 1 to 6.

How can I write my query in such a way that it not only gets objects with state 1 but from 1 to n?

EDIT:

Few information to make this question more clear:

The server can handle a request with state 1 to 6?

I can perfectly do the following requests

```
https://test.com/api?state=1
https://test.com/api?state=2
https://test.com/api?state=3
https://test.com/api?state=4
https://test.com/api?state=5
https://test.com/api?state=6
```

Is there a way to get the same result with only one request?
Or does that depend on how the api works?

Comment: That depends entirely on how test.com/api works.

Comment: Yes, it can. If it doesn't work for you, perhaps you're using a language that decodes GET parameters automatically and you failed to use the supported syntax.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It looks like your comment is in reply to the title, but ignores everything in the actual question.

Comment: @melpomene I normally take for granted that the title (the most visible part of a question) has at least some relevance to the question being asked. Who would fill it with random text? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> "Let's assume that state can take a value from 1 to 6"

What assumption do you make here? the server can handle a request with state 1 to 6?

> "How can I write my query in such a way that it not only gets objects with state 1 but from 1 to n?"

sounds like you need to handle this issue on test.com/api GET request code, on the server side.

Comment: Yes I assume that the server can handle a request with state 1 to 6. Let's say for state 1 it returns all objects with state 1. How can I ask all objects with state 1 or state 2?